# Issue with binary field and named query - nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am using nHibernate to try and log a user in using a named query but their password is hashed and so stored as a binary field in the MS SQL DB. However I can't get the login code to work. It throws an error:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
  user = (CreamUser)session.GetNamedQuery("loginuser")
         .SetString("UserName", userName)
         .SetBinary("Password", hashedPassword).UniqueResult();

}

<sql-query name="loginuser">
    <query-param name="UserName" type="string" />
    <query-param name="Password" type="binary" />
    <return alias="User" class="components.User"/>
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT * FROM users 
    WHERE username=:UserName AND 
    password=:Password 
    ]]>
</sql-query>
```

I have tried everything I can think of but can't get this to work.

Comment: Which error? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I worked it out. I turns out it was to do with the fact the the query I was executing was missing some fields that matched with the type (user) that I was returning.

this was the error in case anyone else comes across this issue:

could not execute query\r\n[ SELECT * FROM users \n    WHERE username=@p0 AND \n
password=@p1 ]\r\n  Name:UserName - Value:admin  Name:Password - Value:System.Byte[]\r\n[SQL: 
SELECT * FROM users \n    WHERE username=@p0 AND \n    password=@p1]

thanks for making me look deeper ExpectoPatronum